# Can we access another application's class or fire an intent to another application's class from our application?

Tags: android

I want to fire an intent to another application's activity .
What i am thinking is to use intent filter of the other's.
Or can i access the other application package in some other way?

Suppose My app is 'A' and another app also exist in phone which is 'B'

Q1. Can I access or call classes of B and its method by any means?
Q2. And If it can be done by Implicit Intents then What happens in that case where I cant have access of B's Source code, means I cannot find the B's class Intent filter.

Comment: use intent that is the prescribed way of doing it in android

Comment: You can only use an Intent to launch a component of a foreign package which has an Intent filter.  Technically you don't need the source code if you have the apk as the binary manifest can be converted back to readable form.

Comment: Oh. ok thanks. Once an Interviewer asked me How to use an other application from our Application?. I had no answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to access another app's class?